# In a javaFX dialog my button:pressed style works with mouse click but not for keyboard

Tags: css, fxml

I have a dialog in my JavaFX application with a button.  When I click the button with a mouse, it shows the .button:pressed style, a greenish glow in my case.  When I use a keyboard there is no indication of the press.  However, the button function works, so I know it had focus when I pressed the space bar or Enter key.

Here is the relavent portion of my css file.

.button:pressed
{
-fx-background-color: radial-gradient(center 50% 50%, radius 80%, #0080ff, #000000);
}

I have tried using .button:active with no luck
Also tried .button:active:focus
And tried removing .button:focus in case one was taking precidence.

Thanks,
Tony

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled into the "armed" style on another post.

Armed is similar to pressed except it also indicates that the button action will be taken when the mouse is released.  This difference does not seem to matter for what I am doing but I tired it anyway.

For whatever reason, the mouse and keyboard both fire off this style when pressed.

Tony